# Stripe API - How to Retrieve a Plan or Price "currency_options" property?

Tags: stripe-payments

There is ways to UPDATE or CREATE the `Plan.currency_options` or `Price.currency_options` property on the API request, but there is a way to retrieve the `currency_options` property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you look at the API Reference for the Price [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object), you can see all the properties that are associated with that object. You will see the `currency_options` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object#price_object-currency_options). Next to it it says `Expandable` which means it's not returned by default unless you ask for it.

You can read more about the Expand feature in the [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/expand), specifically about how to include properties not returned by default [here](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#includable-properties).

To summarize, you call the Retrieve Price [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/retrieve) and pass `expand: ['currency_options']` to get those back.

Comment: Thank you! This Expandable prop it's almost invisible in the "Price" documentation!

Comment: Thanks! For those really lazy, it's `const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve(priceId, {expand: ['currency_options']})`